# What data type does the MySql Connector/NET map Guids to?

Tags: .net, mysql

We are considering switching to MySQL for our application.  Our code makes extensive use of Guids.  What data type does the MySQL Connector for .NET map Guids to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that MySQL supports writing `Guids` to the database as either `CHAR(36)` or `BINARY(16)`.

It also turns out that `CHAR(36)` is space inefficient and `BINARY(16)` is processor inefficient if you have a lot of rows in your table.  Performance is horrible because it makes 16 byte comparisons instead of a 128-bit integer comparison.

We decided not to go with MySQL.